# In-App purchase , Cancel the purchase because of long processing time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storekit

I was implementing In-App purchase to my game and its working fine. No problem with the purchases and other stuffs. But today i was stuck at a weird point.

When the user tries to purchase , sometimes it takes more than a minute to get respond from Apple. (Sandbox environment).

What i want to do is just to put a cancel button in an `UIAlertView` , which will help the user to cancel the whole purchase. So the user can cancel the purchase, if there is a delay in Sandbox respond. How can i do this ?

I already have a UIAlertView which starts with the purchase button click and ends with the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` method. I want to add that cancel button to that alertview.

Confused and here is my question in short again ,

But what is the method should be called to cancel the whole In-App processes while it is on the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` state ?

Comment: sometimes it happened. you cannot cancel the request after you've sent it, you should wait the answer. the user **can** cancel it, when the application gets response from the server and this option shows on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant interrupt the request once it sent. You should wait until Apple responds.